# How to change the styling of a component in another component ? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-styleguidist

First I apologize if this question has been answered elsewhere. I'm still learning.

Assuming we have a parent component  that has children components inside of it, so :

in App.js:

```
 <>
        <Advertisement title="Free Shipping For Orders Above 150 USD ! " />
        <NavBar />
        <LandingSection />
        <Featured />
        <Explore />
        <Shop />
        <RecommendedVideos />
        <AsSeenOn />
        <Footer />
      </>
```

Now, we all know that each component has it own css file, however, if I want to change specific CSS attributes/styles to fit with the new component and I just want it in this specific component, in our case it is  `App.js`. What should I do ? any tutorials on this topic ?

**Also ... What is the difference between using**

```
import styles from './styles.css 

className = {styles.someName}
```

and using

`styled-components` library ?

**and most importantly, in professional/real-world apps, what method do developers use ?**

Comment: This is opinion based. Without requirements this is just a decade-long debate.

Answer (score -2):

Each component should use either css modules or styled component. That way style will be scoped to that component.

If you use plain css then it might clash with other components styles.

Comment: Any examples? illustrations?

Comment: For css modules, please find detailed example [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/). For styled component basic examples is [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics)